# jQuery UI range slider tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

How can I get my jQuery UI range slider to display tooltips on top of the markers like so:

[image]

```
 <span class="tooltip"></span> <div id="slider-range"></div>
 <button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="reset_slider('#slider-range')">Reset</button>
```

Here is the script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#slider-range").slider({
         min: 0,
         max: 1000,
         step: 1,
         range: true,
         values: [0, 1000],
         slide: function(event, ui) {
             for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                 $("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
             }
         }
     });

     $("input.sliderValue").change(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
         $("#slider-range").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());

     });
 });
```

Here is how it looks right now, all its missing is the tooltips on top.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine two examples:

- http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range
- http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/c90ee4xe/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slider-range">
  </div>
  <a href="" id="reset" class="btn btn-success">Reset</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#slider-range {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 20px;
}

#slider-range .ui-slider-handle {
  background: #0e6;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#slider-range .ui-slider-handle.ui-state-active {
  border: #093;
}

#slider-range .ui-slider-range {
  background: #093;
}

.ui-tooltip,
.arrow:after {
  background: #000;
}

.ui-tooltip {
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.arrow {
  width: 70px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35px;
  bottom: -16px;
}

.arrow.top {
  top: -16px;
  bottom: auto;
}

.arrow.left {
  left: 20%;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: -20px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow.top:after {
  bottom: -20px;
  top: auto;
}

#reset {
  color: #fff;
  background: #090;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    step: 1,
    range: true,
    values: [0, 1000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var low, high;
      low = $(this).slider("values", 0);
      high = $(this).slider("values", 1);
      $(this).tooltip("option", "content", low + ":" + high);
    }
  });

  $("#slider-range").tooltip({
    items: ".ui-slider",
    content: "0:1000",
    position: {
      my: "center bottom-20",
      at: "center top",
      using: function(position, feedback) {
        $(this).css(position);
        $("<div>")
          .addClass("arrow")
          .addClass(feedback.vertical)
          .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
          .appendTo(this);
      }
    }
  });

  $("#reset").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#slider-range").slider("values", [0, 1000]).tooltip("option", "content", "0:1000").tooltip("close");
  });
});
```

For the Slider, we do most everything the same. Just in `slide` we update the `content` of the tooltip instead of fields.

For this example, we're only using 1 tooltip on 1 slider. If you have multiple sliders, see: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content It will be more complex. If you have a smaller number of sliders, you can just make a tooltip for each. Otherwise it'll need the `item` option set and some ways to tie specific sliders to their tooltip.

The tooltip is pretty straight forward. We'll set the `content` to our intial value since we know it will be changed later. We also set the `position` that will be fluid. This helps move the tooltip above or below depending on the `feedback` and we style the arrow to correspond.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, will try it on friday and will post reply!